# Easily Enter Math Notation On The Web

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, web-applications

Is there a react library solution that let user easily enter math notations and translate it to latex in the backend? I mean like a user friendly editor with clickable buttons maybe? And in the back end it will convert those elements to Latex

Comment: What kind of notation infix or RPN (reverse-polish notation)?

Answer (score 0):

You could try MathJax. Version 3 is the latest and it is very robust.

It is the best JavaScript LaTeX renderer according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3284131/is-there-a-javascript-latex-equation-renderer).

In the example below, you can either render existing content to LaTeX, or add elements dynamically.

```js
const expressions = [
  '\\frac{a}{b}',
  '\(V = {4 \\over 3} \pi^3 \)'
];

document.querySelectorAll('.expression').forEach(el => {
  el.replaceWith(MathJax.tex2chtml(el.textContent));
});

expressions.forEach(expression => {
  document.body.append(MathJax.tex2chtml(expression));
});
```

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}

body > * {
  border: thin solid grey;
  padding: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-chtml.js"></script>
<div class="expression">(\int_{a}^{b} x^2 \,dx)</div>
```

### Parse infix notation to LaTeX

If you want to interpret expressions and convert them to LaTeX, you can try this:

```js
const form = document.forms['latex-add'];
const container = document.querySelector('#expression-list');
const expressions = ['\\frac{a}{b}', '\\frac{{(25 \\cdot 5)}}{6}'];

const main = () => {
  form.elements.expression.value = '(25*5)/b';
  form.addEventListener('submit', handleAdd);
  renderExpressions();
};

const handleAdd = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const expression = e.target.elements.expression.value.trim();
  const tex = texFromExpression(expression);
  console.log(tex);
  expressions.push(tex);
  renderExpressions();
  e.target.reset();
};

const renderExpressions = () => {
  container.innerHTML = '';
  expressions.forEach(expression => {
    const wrapper = document.createElement('div');
    wrapper.classList.add('expression');
    const tex = document.createElement('div');
    tex.classList.add('tex');
    tex.textContent = expression;
    wrapper.append(tex);
    wrapper.append(MathJax.tex2chtml(expression));
    container.append(wrapper);
  });
};

// Credit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57449164/1762224
const texFromExpression = (str) => {
  let pos = -1, ch;

  const nextChar = () => {
    ch = (++pos < str.length) ? str.charAt(pos) : -1;
  };

  const eat = (charToEat) => {
    while (ch == ' ') nextChar();
    if (ch == charToEat) {
      nextChar();
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  };

  const parse = () => {
    nextChar();
    const x = parseExpression();
    if (pos < str.length) throw new Error(`Unexpected: ${ch}`)
    return x;
  };

  const parseExpression = () => {
    let x = parseTerm();
    while (true) {
      if (eat('+')) x = `${x} + ${parseTerm()}` // addition
      else if (eat('-')) x = `${x} - ${parseTerm()}` // subtraction
      else return x;
    }
  };

  const parseTerm = () => {
    var x = parseFactor();
    while (true) {
      if (eat('*')) x = `${x} \\cdot ${parseTerm()}`; // multiplication
      else if (eat('/')) x = `\\frac{${x}}{${parseTerm()}}`; // division
      else return x;
    }
  };

  const parseFactor = () => {
    if (eat('+')) return parseFactor(); // unary plus
    if (eat('-')) return `-${parseFactor()}`; // unary minus
    let x;
    const startPos = pos;
    if (eat('(')) { // parentheses
      x = `{(${parseExpression()})}`
      eat(')');
    } else if ((ch >= '0' && ch <= '9') || ch == '.') { // numbers
      while ((ch >= '0' && ch <= '9') || ch == '.') nextChar();
      x = str.substring(startPos, pos);
    } else if (ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z') { // variables
      while (ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z') nextChar();
      x = str.substring(startPos, pos);
      if (x.length > 1) {
        x = `\\${x} {${parseFactor()}}`;
      }
    } else {
      throw new Error(`Unexpected: ${ch}`);
    }
    if (eat('^')) x = `${x} ^ {${parseFactor()}}` // superscript
    if (eat('_')) x = `${x}_{${parseFactor()}}`;
    return x;
  }
  return parse();
}

main();
```

```css
#expression-list {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 0.5rem;
}

.expression {
  padding: 0.5rem;
  border: thin solid grey;
}

.tex {
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: smaller;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-chtml.js"></script>
<form name="latex-add" autocomplete="off">
  <label for="expression">Expression:</label>
  <input type="text" id="expression" name="expression"
         value="" placeholder="Expression..." />
  <button type="submit">Add</button>
</form>
<hr />
<div id="expression-list"></div>
```

Comment: I am aware of MathJax, my question was more on the user side. I want them to be able to enter math notation without knowing any Latex. Think of a UI like many stack overflow where you click certains formatting buttons and it automatically change your text to the appropriate markdown format

Comment: @NguyễnDuy my second example transforms standard infix into LaTeX format, adds it to a list and (tries to) render it.